# Changing root password via DOCKERFILE

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Nevermind the security implications, I'd like to change the root password via the DOCKERFILE.  Is there a way to do this?  I figured that the below line would work, however, it doesn't.

```
RUN echo "root:Password" | chpasswd
```